# Translated URL with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I use React Router in my isomorphic react project, I have a working router but I am wondering how to translate urls and use the same handler.

For example :

> /en/user => handler is userComponent
>
> /fr/utilisateur => handler is userComponent

I read a lot of documentation and the only solution I found is to make three blocks of routes but I think it should exist a better solution.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm trying to solve this too T_T